# Django - Broken in Mozilla and not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a serious problem.. :

```
[06/Jul/2015 14:48:25] "POST /mf HTTP/1.1" 200 26969
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 212, in write
self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    [06/Jul/2015 14:48:25] "POST /mf HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 34036)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

only when I use location.reload() or location.href in my js method.

In fact, on click on a button, my js method get elements of a form and send this elements to my view ($.POST(...)). My view uses this elements and render to a html page (`return render(request,"web_site/mf.html",locals())`). But this render doesn't works...

Error only on Mozilla...

In my JS method :

```
function envoie_post_competences(){
    var tab = document.getElementsByName("lesPrec");
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/mf",{"lsC[]": tab});
    location.href = location.href;
}
```

My url :

```
...
url(r'^mf$','mf',name="mf"),
...
```

And my view :

```
def mf(request):
    pseudo=request.user.username
    i_user = get_object_or_404(User,username=pseudo)
    eater = Inscrit.objects.get(user=i_user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        requete = request.POST
        ....
    return render(request,"le_site/mf.html",locals())
```

In search a solution but in don't find...

Comment: Maybe this is of use? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444

Comment: I don't know how code.djangoproject works lol... I search...

Comment: But I prefer a manual solution and not download a source code of a person

Comment: Can you clarify your issue? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is that JS method? What do you mean: "In found a solution but in don't find..."?

Comment: I don't find issue, I a make a mistake. But why I have this problem in Mozilla and not in Chrome ?

Comment: Why is that  "serious" problem? It's an annoying line in your log, but that's all, surely?

Comment: By this line is not normal... See my message, I will edit

Comment: I posted all error in my message

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, I use .done() of $post ! 
Thank you.